# How to deploy naive Bayes model on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, naivebayes

I have a naive Bayes model which performs sentiment analysis of movie reviews. I want to deploy this naive Bayes model on AWS Sagemaker. Naive Bayes isn't one of the built in algorithms on Sagemaker.

Can anyone guide me with the steps ? I already have the model built and I'm just left with deploying it on Sagemaker so that I can build a web app using its endpoint instance

Answer (score 0):

If it's based on Sklearn/Numpy/Scipy pandas or if you can install it by `pip` I recommend you use the SageMaker Sklearn container ; you can follow [an example here with a Sklearn random forest](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb)  and [here is the doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html) explaining you how to format your code and add custom pip dependencies with a `requirements.txt`